# Add image byte array in JRDesignImage

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports

I have a byte array that represents an image.

I need to use this byte array in reports generated through JasperReport API 6.20.

Passing the image path is out of scope in this case.

```
byte[] image = [0,0,0,0,0]
JRDesignImage jrDesignImage = new JRDesignImage()
jrDesignImage.setX(width)
jrDesignImage.setY(0)
jrDesignImage.setWidth(width)
jrDesignImage.setHeight(height)
jrDesignImage.setOnErrorType(OnErrorTypeEnum.BLANK)
```

I tried to use JRDesignExpression, with base64, but error occurs due to the length of the string.

```
String b64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image)
JRDesignExpression expressionApp = new JRDesignExpression()
expressionApp.setText('"' + b64 + '"')
//expressionApp.setText(b64)
expressionApp.setValueClass(String)
imageApp.setExpression(expressionApp)
```

I'm using Java 11.0.17, Grails 5.2.2 and JasperReports API 6.20

Answer (score 1):

### 1. JasperPrint + JRBasePrintImage usage

#### 1.1 Solution in case using byte array

Try to use *[JRPrintImage](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRPrintImage.html)* (*[JRBasePrintImage](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBasePrintImage.html)* implementation) for showing image.

The *[JRPrintImage.setRenderer(net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.Renderable)](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRPrintImage.html#setRenderer(net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.Renderable))* method can be used for setting image renderer. The *[SimpleDataRenderer](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/renderers/SimpleDataRenderer.html)* implementation of renderer can be used for showing image passed as byte array.

#### 1.2 Working example on Java

This code is showing report with image that was read from the file and was passed to renderer as byte array.

```
private static JasperPrint getJasperPrint() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = new JasperPrint();
    jasperPrint.setPageWidth(500);
    jasperPrint.setPageHeight(400);

    JRPrintPage page = new JRBasePrintPage();

    byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(BuildReportWithImage.class.getResource("/smile.jpg").toURI()));

    JRPrintImage image = new JRBasePrintImage(jasperPrint.getDefaultStyleProvider());
    image.setX(45);
    image.setY(55);
    image.setWidth(88);
    image.setHeight(88);
    image.setScaleImage(ScaleImageEnum.FILL_FRAME);
    image.setRenderer(SimpleDataRenderer.getInstance(imageBytes));
    page.addElement(image);

    JRPrintText text = new JRBasePrintText(jasperPrint.getDefaultStyleProvider());
    text.setX(150);
    text.setY(55);
    text.setWidth(345);
    text.setHeight(30);
    text.setTextHeight(text.getHeight());
    text.setFontSize(12f);
    text.setText("Example of rendering image using byte array with \nhelp of SimpleDataRenderer");
    page.addElement(text);

    jasperPrint.addPage(page);

    return jasperPrint;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(getJasperPrint(), false);
    jasperViewer.setTitle("Show image using byte array");
    jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
}
```

#### 1.3 Output

This is the result of running the code above:

[image]

### 2. JasperDesign + JRDesignImage usage

#### 2.1 Solution in case using byte array

In case we have to use *JasperDesign* (for example, we need different bands) we can do a similar trick with the *SimpleDataRenderer*.

We can't set the byte array directly in case using *JRDesignImage*, but we can write expression (Java expression) that will use *SimpleDataRenderer* because image expression supports *Renderable* object.

#### 2.2 Working example on Java

We can init the instance of *Renderable* object with expression like this:

```
Renderable renderable = SimpleDataRenderer.getInstance(someByteArray);
```

The full snippet:

```
private static JasperDesign getJasperDesign() throws JRException, URISyntaxException, IOException {
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = new JasperDesign();
    jasperDesign.setName("ShowingImage");
    jasperDesign.setPageWidth(595);
    jasperDesign.setPageHeight(400);
    jasperDesign.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.NO_DATA_SECTION);

    JRDesignBand titleBand = new JRDesignBand();
    titleBand.setHeight(100);

    JRDesignStaticText staticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
    staticText.setX(120);
    staticText.setY(10);
    staticText.setWidth(400);
    staticText.setHeight(60);
    staticText.setHorizontalTextAlign(HorizontalTextAlignEnum.CENTER);
    staticText.setFontSize(12f);
    staticText.setText("Example of rendering image [JRDesignImage] using byte array with \nhelp of SimpleDataRenderer");
    titleBand.addElement(staticText);

    JRDesignImage image = new JRDesignImage(DEFAULT_STYLE_PROVIDER);
    image.setX(1);
    image.setY(1);
    image.setWidth(88);
    image.setHeight(88);
    image.setOnErrorType(OnErrorTypeEnum.ERROR);
    image.setExpression(new JRDesignExpression("net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.SimpleDataRenderer.getInstance(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Paths.get(ru.alex.BuildReportWithImage.class.getResource(\"/earth.jpg\").toURI())))"));
    titleBand.addElement(image);

    jasperDesign.setTitle(titleBand);

    return jasperDesign;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = getJasperDesign();
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.getInstance(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance()).compile(jasperDesign);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<>(), new JREmptyDataSource());

    JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
    jasperViewer.setTitle("Show image using byte array");
    jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
}
```

#### 2.3 Output

This is the result of running the code above:

[image]

Comment: Cool, but the image must be in the header of a JasperDesign, using the setPageHeader method, this method only accepts JRDesignBand type objects.

Comment: @JoãoG.Hartmann I've added a sample with JasperDesign & JRDesignImage

Comment: You mean something like that `new JRDesignExpression("net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.SimpleDataRenderer.getInstance(${someByteArray})")`?
'Cause when you use this `new JRDesignExpression("net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.SimpleDataRenderer.getInstance(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Paths.get(ru.alex.BuildReportWithImage.class.getResource(\"/earth.jpg\").toURI())))")` the someByteArray aren't in use right?

Comment: `Files.readAllBytes` returnes byte array. It is example of how we can pass byte array.

Comment: I tried `expression.setText('net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.SimpleDataRenderer.getInstance(' + someByteArray + ')')`, but it did not work. No errors and the image is not displayed

Comment: @JoãoG.Hartmann Looks like you doing something wrong